# JSP and Javascript conflict I think

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, conflict, jquery-events

I have a HTML file with a form. When I change it as a jsp file and place in some jsp code the Javascript stop responds and nothing happens. It's just a currency converter and the swap button is managed through Javascript.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#swap').click(function() { 
                s1=$('#to').val();  
                s0=$('#from').val();  
                $('#to').val(s0);  
                $('#from').val(s1); 
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    
    <div class="background"></div>
    
    <div id="heading">
        <%
        String currency = (String)request.getAttribute("currency");
        if( currency == null )
        {
            out.print("live currency converter");
        }else{
            out.println("Currency Converted: " +currency);
        }
        %>
    </div>
    
<div id="currencyBox">
<form method="POST" action="CurrencyConverter.do">

    <div class="data">
        <label for="from">Convert:</label>
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <label for="fromCurrency">From Currency:</label>
        <select name="from" id="from">
          <option selected="" value="EUR">Euro - EUR</option>
          <option value="USD">United States Dollars - USD</option>
          <option value="GBP">United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="data">
        <label for="to">To Currency:</label>
        <select name="to" id="to">
          <option value="USD">United States Dollars - USD</option>
          <option value="GBP">United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
          <option value="CAD">Canada Dollars - CAD</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Convert the input">
        <input type="button" name="swap" id="swap" value="Swap values">
    </div>
</form>
<form method="GET" action="CodeGrabber.do"><input type="submit" value="Grab the code!"></form>
<form method="GET" action="ListenTest.do"><input type="submit" value="On line report!"></form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I remove the `<%  %>` parts of code the Javascript on the top works like a charm.
I'm not familiar with jsp and servlets, I have a PHP background!

Here is my output from developer mode:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>currency converter</title>
    <meta name="description" content="currency converter">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/c/styles.css">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="fizaboun/3w lesson"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#swap').click(function() { 
     Â          s1=$('#to').val(); Â 
     Â          s0=$('#from').val(); Â 
     Â          $('#to').val(s0); Â 
     Â          $('#from').val(s1); 
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    
    
    <div class="background"></div>
    
    <div id="heading">
            live currency converter
    </div>
    
<div id="currencyBox">
<form method="POST" action="CurrencyConverter.do">

    <div class="data">
        <label for="from">Convert:</label>
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <label for="fromCurrency">From Currency:</label>
        <select name="from" id="from">
          <option selected="" value="EUR">Euro - EUR</option>
          <option value="USD">United States Dollars - USD</option>
          <option value="GBP">United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
          <option value="CAD">Canada Dollars - CAD</option>
          <option value="AUD">Australia Dollars - AUD</option>
          <option value="JPY">Japan Yen - JPY</option>
          <option value="INR">India Rupees - INR</option>
          <option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollars - NZD</option>
          <option value="CHF">Switzerland Francs - CHF</option>
          <option value="ZAR">South Africa Rand - ZAR</option>
          <option value="DZD">Algeria Dinars - DZD</option>
          <option value="USD">America (United States) Dollars - USD</option>
          <option value="ARS">Argentina Pesos - ARS</option>
          <option value="AUD">Australia Dollars - AUD</option>
          <option value="BHD">Bahrain Dinars - BHD</option>
          <option value="BRL">Brazil Reais - BRL</option>
          <option value="BGN">Bulgaria Leva - BGN</option>
          <option value="CAD">Canada Dollars - CAD</option>
          <option value="CLP">Chile Pesos - CLP</option>
          <option value="CNY">China Yuan Renminbi - CNY</option>
          <option value="CNY">RMB (China Yuan Renminbi) - CNY</option>
          <option value="COP">Colombia Pesos - COP</option>
          <option value="CRC">Costa Rica Colones - CRC</option>
          <option value="HRK">Croatia Kuna - HRK</option>
          <option value="CZK">Czech Republic Koruny - CZK</option>
          <option value="DKK">Denmark Kroner - DKK</option>
          <option value="DOP">Dominican Republic Pesos - DOP</option>
          <option value="EGP">Egypt Pounds - EGP</option>
          <option value="EEK">Estonia Krooni - EEK</option>
          <option value="EUR">Euro - EUR</option>
          <option value="FJD">Fiji Dollars - FJD</option>
          <option value="HKD">Hong Kong Dollars - HKD</option>
          <option value="HUF">Hungary Forint - HUF</option>
          <option value="ISK">Iceland Kronur - ISK</option>
          <option value="INR">India Rupees - INR</option>
          <option value="IDR">Indonesia Rupiahs - IDR</option>
          <option value="ILS">Israel New Shekels - ILS</option>
          <option value="JMD">Jamaica Dollars - JMD</option>
          <option value="JPY">Japan Yen - JPY</option>
          <option value="JOD">Jordan Dinars - JOD</option>
          <option value="KES">Kenya Shillings - KES</option>
          <option value="KRW">Korea (South) Won - KRW</option>
          <option value="KWD">Kuwait Dinars - KWD</option>
          <option value="LBP">Lebanon Pounds - LBP</option>
          <option value="MYR">Malaysia Ringgits - MYR</option>
          <option value="MUR">Mauritius Rupees - MUR</option>
          <option value="MXN">Mexico Pesos - MXN</option>
          <option value="MAD">Morocco Dirhams - MAD</option>
          <option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollars - NZD</option>
          <option value="NOK">Norway Kroner - NOK</option>
          <option value="OMR">Oman Rials - OMR</option>
          <option value="PKR">Pakistan Rupees - PKR</option>
          <option value="PEN">Peru Nuevos Soles - PEN</option>
          <option value="PHP">Philippines Pesos - PHP</option>
          <option value="PLN">Poland Zlotych - PLN</option>
          <option value="QAR">Qatar Riyals - QAR</option>
          <option value="RON">Romania New Lei - RON</option>
          <option value="RUB">Russia Rubles - RUB</option>
          <option value="SAR">Saudi Arabia Riyals - SAR</option>
          <option value="SGD">Singapore Dollars - SGD</option>
          <option value="SKK">Slovakia Koruny - SKK</option>
          <option value="ZAR">South Africa Rand - ZAR</option>
          <option value="KRW">South Korea Won - KRW</option>
          <option value="LKR">Sri Lanka Rupees - LKR</option>
          <option value="SEK">Sweden Kronor - SEK</option>
          <option value="CHF">Switzerland Francs - CHF</option>
          <option value="TWD">Taiwan New Dollars - TWD</option>
          <option value="THB">Thailand Baht - THB</option>
          <option value="TTD">Trinidad and Tobago Dollars - TTD</option>
          <option value="TND">Tunisia Dinars - TND</option>
          <option value="TRY">Turkey Lira - TRY</option>
          <option value="AED">United Arab Emirates Dirhams - AED</option>
          <option value="GBP">United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
          <option value="USD">United States Dollars - USD</option>
          <option value="VEB">Venezuela Bolivares - VEB</option>
          <option value="VND">Vietnam Dong - VND</option>
          <option value="ZMK">Zambia Kwacha - ZMK</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="data">
        <label for="to">To Currency:</label>
        <select name="to" id="to">
          <option value="USD">United States Dollars - USD</option>
          <option value="GBP">United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
          <option value="CAD">Canada Dollars - CAD</option>
          <option value="AUD">Australia Dollars - AUD</option>
          <option value="JPY">Japan Yen - JPY</option>
          <option value="INR">India Rupees - INR</option>
          <option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollars - NZD</option>
          <option value="CHF">Switzerland Francs - CHF</option>
          <option value="ZAR">South Africa Rand - ZAR</option>
          <option value="DZD">Algeria Dinars - DZD</option>
          <option value="USD">America (United States) Dollars - USD</option>
          <option value="ARS">Argentina Pesos - ARS</option>
          <option value="AUD">Australia Dollars - AUD</option>
          <option value="BHD">Bahrain Dinars - BHD</option>
          <option value="BRL">Brazil Reais - BRL</option>
          <option value="BGN">Bulgaria Leva - BGN</option>
          <option value="CAD">Canada Dollars - CAD</option>
          <option value="CLP">Chile Pesos - CLP</option>
          <option value="CNY">China Yuan Renminbi - CNY</option>
          <option value="CNY">RMB (China Yuan Renminbi) - CNY</option>
          <option value="COP">Colombia Pesos - COP</option>
          <option value="CRC">Costa Rica Colones - CRC</option>
          <option value="HRK">Croatia Kuna - HRK</option>
          <option value="CZK">Czech Republic Koruny - CZK</option>
          <option value="DKK">Denmark Kroner - DKK</option>
          <option value="DOP">Dominican Republic Pesos - DOP</option>
          <option value="EGP">Egypt Pounds - EGP</option>
          <option value="EEK">Estonia Krooni - EEK</option>
          <option value="EUR">Euro - EUR</option>
          <option value="FJD">Fiji Dollars - FJD</option>
          <option value="HKD">Hong Kong Dollars - HKD</option>
          <option value="HUF">Hungary Forint - HUF</option>
          <option value="ISK">Iceland Kronur - ISK</option>
          <option value="INR">India Rupees - INR</option>
          <option value="IDR">Indonesia Rupiahs - IDR</option>
          <option value="ILS">Israel New Shekels - ILS</option>
          <option value="JMD">Jamaica Dollars - JMD</option>
          <option value="JPY">Japan Yen - JPY</option>
          <option value="JOD">Jordan Dinars - JOD</option>
          <option value="KES">Kenya Shillings - KES</option>
          <option value="KRW">Korea (South) Won - KRW</option>
          <option value="KWD">Kuwait Dinars - KWD</option>
          <option value="LBP">Lebanon Pounds - LBP</option>
          <option value="MYR">Malaysia Ringgits - MYR</option>
          <option value="MUR">Mauritius Rupees - MUR</option>
          <option value="MXN">Mexico Pesos - MXN</option>
          <option value="MAD">Morocco Dirhams - MAD</option>
          <option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollars - NZD</option>
          <option value="NOK">Norway Kroner - NOK</option>
          <option value="OMR">Oman Rials - OMR</option>
          <option value="PKR">Pakistan Rupees - PKR</option>
          <option value="PEN">Peru Nuevos Soles - PEN</option>
          <option value="PHP">Philippines Pesos - PHP</option>
          <option value="PLN">Poland Zlotych - PLN</option>
          <option value="QAR">Qatar Riyals - QAR</option>
          <option value="RON">Romania New Lei - RON</option>
          <option value="RUB">Russia Rubles - RUB</option>
          <option value="SAR">Saudi Arabia Riyals - SAR</option>
          <option value="SGD">Singapore Dollars - SGD</option>
          <option value="SKK">Slovakia Koruny - SKK</option>
          <option value="ZAR">South Africa Rand - ZAR</option>
          <option value="KRW">South Korea Won - KRW</option>
          <option value="LKR">Sri Lanka Rupees - LKR</option>
          <option value="SEK">Sweden Kronor - SEK</option>
          <option value="CHF">Switzerland Francs - CHF</option>
          <option value="TWD">Taiwan New Dollars - TWD</option>
          <option value="THB">Thailand Baht - THB</option>
          <option value="TTD">Trinidad and Tobago Dollars - TTD</option>
          <option value="TND">Tunisia Dinars - TND</option>
          <option value="TRY">Turkey Lira - TRY</option>
          <option value="AED">United Arab Emirates Dirhams - AED</option>
          <option value="GBP">United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
          <option value="USD">United States Dollars - USD</option>
          <option value="VEB">Venezuela Bolivares - VEB</option>
          <option value="VND">Vietnam Dong - VND</option>
          <option value="ZMK">Zambia Kwacha - ZMK</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Convert the input">
        <input type="button" name="swap" id="swap" value="Swap values">
    </div>
</form>
<form method="GET" action="CodeGrabber.do"><input type="submit" value="Grab the code!"></form>
<form method="GET" action="ListenTest.do"><input type="submit" value="On line report!"></form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And that's how even Java can look like a plain old PHP script :).

Comment: At a glance, I don't see what could be causing this. Post the actual browser source output of the page. As Balus mentioned, JSP is not your root problem.

Comment: Based on your comment on my deleted answer, you have not posted a real SSCCE. You have posted a halfbaked, oversimplified and incomplete code snippet which does not represent your real problem. Please run the code yourself before presenting it as an example.

Comment: no it's named index.jsp and yes there is no java/jsp code in developer mode

Comment: i edited my post now it has the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "developer mode" - is that what you see when you load your page in the browser and click "view source"? - but the following JavaScript is invalid because of all of the "Â" characters. Where do they come from?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#swap').click(function() {
   Â          s1=$('#to').val(); Â
   Â          s0=$('#from').val(); Â
   Â          $('#to').val(s0); Â
   Â          $('#from').val(s1);
          });
     });
```

I don't see any way that your Java code in the `<% %>` tags could be causing any problems.

Comment: yes that is strange too but this characters only exist when i place into the code the <% %> otherwise the just disappear and javascript runs smoothly again... I can't see those characters  in my IDE (coda). they don't exist there.